# Library in PHP/JS/etc to parse date-time with errors?

Tags: validation, datetime, ocr

We are doing OCR (Optical Image Recognition) but 1-in-20 occasions date-time includes errors.

For example:

```
SUN May 2S, 2016 1:30pm //see S instead of 9
TUE May l7, 2016 7:00pm //see l instead of 1
TUE May 1O, 2016 11:25am //see O instead of 0
etc...
```

I think there should be a way for computer to understand what date-time is. Especially considering that date of the week is always correct and each month has only 4-5 those days of the week.

In first line example, there are 2 Sundays that have 2X in the date. Those are 22 and 29. But 2S is not similar to 22, but it is similar to 25 or 29. So considering both it is the 29th....

Are there any libraries to do this? Or some code examples? 
Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved with JS and jQuery. It was tricky. Here is a code for demo page, where I've tested on:

SUU Oct 2S, 2016 l:30pm

SAT Sep l7, 2016 7:20pm

TUE Nov i5, 2016 1I:25am

SAA Dec 24, 2016 1:30pm

SUN Sep 11, 2016 3:34pm

TUE Nov i5, 2016 1i:25am

SAA Dec 24, 2016 1:30pm

```
<!doctype html>

<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">

    <title>test</title>
    <meta name="description" content="test">
    <meta name="author" content="test">

    <style type="text/css">
        .grid {
            display: table;
            width: 100%;
            box-sizing: border-box;
        }
        .col-1-2 {
            float: left;
            width: 50%;
            padding: 15px;
            box-sizing: border-box;
        }
        input {
            width: 100%;
            box-sizing: border-box;
            padding: 10px 15px;
            font-size: 15px;
            margin-bottom: -1px;
            outline: none;
        }
        button {
            display: block;
            margin: 20px auto 15px;
            background: linear-gradient(#4285f4,#3a78de);
            border-radius: 2px;
            box-shadow: 0 0 1px #bbb;
            border: none;
            color: white;
            cursor: pointer;
            font-size: 16px;
            padding: 10px 15px;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="grid">
        <button type="" onclick='fix()'>Fix Dates</button>
        <div class="col-1-2 inputs">
            <input type="text" name="" value="SUU Oct 2S, 2016 l:30pm" placeholder="">
            <input type="text" name="" value="SAT Sep l7, 2016 7:20pm" placeholder="">
            <input type="text" name="" value="TUE Nov i5, 2016 1I:25am" placeholder="">
            <input type="text" name="" value="SAA Dec 24, 2016 1:30pm" placeholder="">
            <input type="text" name="" value="SUN Sep 11, 2016 3:34pm" placeholder="">
            <input type="text" name="" value="TUE Nov i5, 2016 1i:25am" placeholder="">
            <input type="text" name="" value="SAA Dec 24, 2016 1:30pm" placeholder="">
        </div>
        <div class="col-1-2 outputs">
            <input type="text" name="" value="" placeholder="">
            <input type="text" name="" value="" placeholder="">
            <input type="text" name="" value="" placeholder="">
            <input type="text" name="" value="" placeholder="">
            <input type="text" name="" value="" placeholder="">
            <input type="text" name="" value="" placeholder="">
            <input type="text" name="" value="" placeholder="">
        </div>
    </div>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/momentjs/2.13.0/moment.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
        var text = " ";
        var subtext = " ";
        var weekday = " ";
        var weekdayFixed = " ";
        var month = " ";
        var monthFixed = " ";
        var i = 0;
        var today = new Date();

        function checkWeekday(weekday,i) {
            if (/MON|TUE|WED|THU|FRI|SAT|SUN/.test(weekday))
                weekday = weekday;
            else if (/MO|M0/.test(weekday)) 
                weekday = 'MON'
            else if (/TU|UE/.test(weekday)) 
                weekday = 'TUE'
            else if (/WE|ED/.test(weekday)) 
                weekday = 'WED'
            else if (/TH|HU/.test(weekday)) 
                weekday = 'THU'
            else if (/FR|RI/.test(weekday)) 
                weekday = 'FRI'
            else if (/SA|AT/.test(weekday)) 
                weekday = 'SAT'
            else if (/SU|UN/.test(weekday)) 
                weekday = 'SUN'
            else if (/M|O|o|0/.test(weekday)) 
                weekday = 'MON'
            else if (/W/.test(weekday)) 
                weekday = 'WED'
            else if (/F|R/.test(weekday)) 
                weekday = 'FRI'
            else if (/A/.test(weekday)) 
                weekday = 'SAT'
            output(weekday+' ',i);
            weekdayFixed = weekday;
        }

        function checkMonth(month,i) {
            if (/Jan|Feb|Mar|Apr|May|Jun|Jul|Aug|Sep|Oct|Nov|Dec/.test(month))
                month = month;
            else if (/Ja|an/.test(month)) 
                month = 'Jan'
            else if (/Fe|eb/.test(month)) 
                month = 'Feb'
            else if (/ar/.test(month)) 
                month = 'Mar'
            else if (/Ap|pr/.test(month)) 
                month = 'Apr'
            else if (/ay/.test(month)) 
                month = 'May'
            else if (/un/.test(month)) 
                month = 'Jun'
            else if (/ul/.test(month)) 
                month = 'Jul'
            else if (/Au|ug/.test(month)) 
                month = 'Aug'
            else if (/Se|ep/.test(month)) 
                month = 'Sep'
            else if (/Oc|ct/.test(month)) 
                month = 'Oct'
            else if (/No|ov/.test(month)) 
                month = 'Nov'
            else if (/De|ec/.test(month)) 
                month = 'Dec'
            output(month+' ',i);
            monthFixed = month;
        }

        function checkDay(day,i) {
            if ([
                    '1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','10',
                    '11','12','13','14','15','16','17','18','19','20',
                    '21','22','23','24','25','26','27','28','29','30','31'
                ].indexOf(day) >= 0) {
                output(day,i);
                for (var j=0; j<=999; j++) {
                    var temp = moment().date(j)._d;
                    if ((temp.toString().indexOf(month) > -1)&&
                       (temp.toString().substr(8,2).indexOf(day) > -1)&&
                       (temp.toString().toUpperCase().indexOf(weekdayFixed) > -1)) {
                            output(', '+temp.toString().substr(11,4)+' ', i);
                            break;
                    }
                }
            } else {
                for (var j=0; j<=999; j++) {
                    var temp = moment().date(j)._d;

                    if ((temp.toString().indexOf(month) > -1)&&
                       (temp.toString().toUpperCase().indexOf(weekdayFixed) > -1)) {
                        var firstDigit = day.match(/\d/);
                        var indexOfFirstDigit = day.indexOf(firstDigit);
                        var dayOnlyNumbers = day.replace(/\D/g,'');
                        if (indexOfFirstDigit == 0) {
                            if (temp.toString().substr(8,1).indexOf(dayOnlyNumbers) > -1) {
                                day = temp.toString().substr(8,2);
                                output(day,i);
                                output(', '+temp.toString().substr(11,4)+' ', i);
                                break;
                            }
                        } else {
                            if (temp.toString().substr(9,1).indexOf(dayOnlyNumbers) > -1) {
                                day = temp.toString().substr(8,2);
                                output(day,i);
                                output(', '+temp.toString().substr(11,4)+' ', i);
                                break;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        function checkTimeH (timeH, i) {
            if (/l|i|I/.test(timeH))
                timeH = timeH.replace(/l|i|I/g, "1");
            output(timeH+':',i);
            timeHFixed = timeH;
        }

        function checkTimeM (timeM, i) {
            if (/l|i|I/.test(timeM))
                timeM = timeM.replace(/l|i|I/g, "1");
            output(timeM,i);
            timeMFixed = timeM;
        }

        function checkTimeAmPm (timeAmPm, i) {
            output(timeAmPm,i);
            timeAmPmFixed = timeAmPm;
        }

        function fix() {
            for (var i = 0; i < $('.inputs input').length; i++) {
                text = $('.outputs input').eq(i).val('');
                text = $('.inputs input').eq(i).val();

                weekday = text.substr(0,text.indexOf(' '));
                subtext = text.slice(text.indexOf(' ')+1);      
                checkWeekday(weekday,i);

                month = subtext.substring(0,subtext.indexOf(' '));
                subtext = subtext.slice(subtext.indexOf(' '));      
                checkMonth(month,i);

                day = subtext.substring(1,subtext.indexOf(','));
                subtext = subtext.slice(subtext.indexOf(',')+2);        
                checkDay(day,i);

                subtext = text.substring(text.lastIndexOf(' ')+1);
                timeH = subtext.substring(0,subtext.indexOf(':'));
                subtext = subtext.slice(subtext.indexOf(':')+1);
                checkTimeH(timeH,i);

                timeM = subtext.substring(0,2);
                subtext = subtext.slice(2);
                checkTimeM(timeM,i);

                timeAmPm = subtext.substring(0,2);
                checkTimeAmPm(timeAmPm,i);
            }
        }

        function output(output,i) {
            $('.outputs input').eq(i).val($('.outputs input').eq(i).val() + output);
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```